# "req.params" not showing JSON data on the webpage as HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning node.js and I was playing around with `req.params` when I stumbled upon a problem. Basically, `req.params` doesn't seem to work, I tried looking for the wrong syntax but it's right. The thing is that the response had a status code of 200 and it showed the document as JSON in the network tab. Please help me fix this issue.

Here is the code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const { products } = require('./data')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1> Home Page</h1><a href="/api/products">products</a>')
})
app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
  res.json(products)
  res.status(200)
})

app.get("/api/products/:num", (req, res) => {
    const { num } = req.params
    const reqProduct = products.find(
        (product) => product.id === Number(num)
    )
    res.json(reqProduct)
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("The server is listening")
})
```

**Here is the dummy data which I am using:**

```
const products = [
    {
        id: "1",
        price: "10",
        description: "qwerty",
        image: "Helooo"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        price: "20",
        description: "qwerty",
        image: "Helooo"
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        price: "30",
        description: "qwerty",
        image: "Helooo"
    }
]

module.exports = { products }
```

And here is how the webpage looks if I try to navigate URL using `req.params`:

[image: The webpage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your `.find()` search in these lines:

```
const reqProduct = products.find(
    (product) => product.id === Number(num)
)
```

`product.id` is a string, and so is `num`. However, you convert `num` to a number first, so `product.id` is not strictly equal (the `===` operator) to `Number(num)` because they have different types. Try not converting `num` to a number:

```
const reqProduct = products.find(
    (product) => product.id === num
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I am sorry for not catching that ,big thx.

Comment: @Spa4k Always happy to help! If my answer worked for you, then you should mark it as correct. This will indicate to other users that my answer helped you.